# Key presses get “remembered” when the beginning or the end of the page is reached

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scroll, keyboard-events

I have an entirely horizontally spread page that one can scroll by pressing, for example, <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> and etc, to navigate.

The problem I have is that if you, for example, press the <kbd>Page Down</kbd> key multiple times when you reach the end of the page, it will take you the same number of <kbd>Page Up</kbd> presses to scroll back. Same happens at the beginning of the page if you, for example, press the <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> multiple times, and then try to go right afterword.

How can I solve this so that key presses don’t get “remembered” when the beginning or the end of the page is reached?

---

You can run my code below:

```js
let scrollAmount = 0
const container = document.documentElement

window.onload = () => {
  document.body.onkeydown = event => {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "Space":
      case "PageDown":
      case "ArrowRight":
      case "ArrowDown": {
        event.preventDefault()
        scrollAmount += window.innerWidth
        break
      }
      case "PageUp":
      case "ArrowLeft":
      case "ArrowUp": {
        event.preventDefault()
        scrollAmount -= window.innerWidth
        break
      }
      case "Home": {
        scrollAmount = 0
        break
      }
      case "End": {
        scrollAmount = container.scrollWidth
        break
      }
    }

    container.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: scrollAmount,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }
}

// Reset the scrollAmount if the user scrolls back manually.
window.onscroll = event => {
  scrollAmount = container.scrollLeft
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html { height: 100% }

html, body, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%
}

section:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background: limeGreen }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background: royalBlue }

h2 { color: white }
```

```html
<section><h2>1</h2></section>
<section><h2>2</h2></section>
<section><h2>3</h2></section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add limits that will stop you from incrementing `scrollAmount` if you're at the start or the end:

- Start - `scrollAmount` is 0
- End - `scrollAmount` is equal to the `body.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth` (the entire width of the body - the width of a page)

```js
let scrollAmount = 0
const container = document.documentElement

window.onload = () => {
  document.body.onkeydown = event => {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "Space":
      case "PageDown":
      case "ArrowRight":
      case "ArrowDown":
        {
          event.preventDefault()
          const maxScroll = container.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth
          if(scrollAmount === maxScroll) return; // if at the end, return
          scrollAmount += window.innerWidth
          break
        }
      case "PageUp":
      case "ArrowLeft":
      case "ArrowUp":
        {
          event.preventDefault()
          
          if(scrollAmount === 0) return; // if at the start return
          scrollAmount -= window.innerWidth
          break
        }
      case "Home":
        {
          scrollAmount = 0
          break
        }
      case "End":
        {
          scrollAmount = container.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth
          break
        }
    }

    container.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: scrollAmount,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }
}

// Reset the scrollAmount if the user scrolls back manually.
window.onscroll = event => {
  scrollAmount = container.scrollLeft
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html { height: 100% }

html, body, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

section:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background: limeGreen }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background: royalBlue }

h2 { color: white }
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>1</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>2</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>3</h2>
</section>
```